# Execute sql query using php

Tags: php, sql, freetds, ubuntu-14.04

I have connected the sql database server using FreeTDS in php. I am trying to execute sql select query in php. I can't able to execute query. I mentioned the program below

```
 <?php
    $empid = 10068;
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO('odbc:Driver=FreeTDS; Server=XXXXXXX; Port=1433; Database=XXXX; UID=XXXXXX; PWD=XXXXX;');
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        die("Unable to open database.<br />Error message:<br /><br />$exception.");
    }
    echo '<h1>Successfully connected!</h1>';
    echo gettype($empid);
    $query = "select Employee_ID from REPT_Employee where Employee_ID=$empid";
    echo $query
    **$statement = $db->prepare($query);** //Getting error in this line
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    echo $result 
 ?>
```

I Can't able to execute the query. Can anyone help me to find out what mistake i did.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i didn't get the error log. the line doesn't work which i highlighted above... now i found the solution.. will answer it...

Comment: now i want to get values from database. can't able to fetch data..

Comment: In PDO you can check query errors by `if(!$statement->execute()) print_r($statement->errorInfo());`

Comment: when i try to fetch data from database am getting the the result like "Array".. I need to get value of particular id which i passed in that query.

Comment: Ohh, I recommend read PHP manual and check how to display array: `foreach()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change like this

```
 $statement = $db->query("select Password from REPT_Employee where Employee_ID=$empid");
 $statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use the `bindParam` function you have to use `prepare` function in this way :

```
$statement = $db->prepare("select Employee_ID from REPT_Employee where Employee_ID='$empid'");
```

Just add quotes `''` to $empid string in the $query string.

Comment: Try to use `bindParam` function : `$statement = $db->prepare("select Employee_ID from REPT_Employee where Employee_ID=:empid");
$statement->bindParam(":empid",$empid);
$statement->execute();`